# g++ linker problem

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to understand the keyword extern in C++ and wrote a short code to outline the meaning. Unfortunately I am doing something wrong

bla.h

```
int bla = 4;
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
       extern int bla;
       cout << bla << endl;
}

g++ -o test bla.h test.cpp
/tmp/ccED67jz.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `bla'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 4):

`extern`, the use you describe only works on globals:

bla.cpp

```
int bla = 4;
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern int bla; // use the global from bla.cpp as a global in this file

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << bla << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it more like this.

test.cpp

```
extern int bla;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << bla << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp

```
int bla;
```

> g++ test.cpp other.cpp

Basically extern is used to make the compiler link the external variable in another object file.  That could be another source file or even an external library.  It also only works on globals.

Comment: It works on local variables too, tried it. The problem was with the .h ending... if i rename it to .cpp it works?!

Answer (score 1):

- never define variables in headers (that is where you should use extern)
- never declare a local extern variable, these variable are always global and declaring them locally causes confusion

What extern means is: Don't create the variable here, it already exists elsewhere. The "elsewhere" part means in a different compilation unit.

For example:

*file1.c*

```
int x;
```

*file2.c*

```
extern int x; /* x already exists in file1.c */

int main()
{
    x = 10;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c
```